# How to move the cursor of a QTMovie?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, quicktime

I have an array of objects that have QTTime structs as attributes.  The objects are in an NSArrayController which is bound to an NSTableView.  I have a QTMovieView set up as an IBOutlet.  I want to have it such that when an item in the NSTableView is selected the QTMovieView's cursor is moved to the time indicated in the selected objects QTTime attribute.  Is there a method that will allow me to move the current time point of a QTMovie to a QTTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [setCurrentTime:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/setCurrentTime:)?

Comment: Thanks!  That was the method I needed!